# cant use store test kit while Working with SQLite in Windows Phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am using SQLite.WP80 version=3.7.16 in Windows phone 8 project.
Now when I tried to test with store test kit it says:

> "the application package(XAP) is not up to date,recompile and try again.
>   change the solution configuration to release and platform to any cpu and rebuild the app"

But as I am using sqllite i cannot change to any cpu.

Can anyone tell possible solution?

Comment: have you added the C++ Runtime Package as a reference? You need this if you are using SQLite (for Windows 8 Store apps at least, I expect it would be the same with phone apps)

Comment: yes i have added all working fine, but cant test the app with store kit

Comment: I found [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18744901/112397) that helped me get the apps testing again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should target just one CPU during development (depending on what machine you will be testing/debugging on). When it's time to publish your app, you can select multiple packages, one for each CPU architecture. Visual Studio will then create several packages, which you can upload to the dev portal.

Comment: can i test the arm build with store kit for windows phone

Comment: No, you'll need a Surface RT or another ARM device

Comment: This is not answer for the question - I have the same problem as well, my WP8 app is using native code and cannot be built in AnyCPU mode and therefore tested using the App Store Kit.