# Possible to use the Windows Phone 8 Store Test Kit with Custom Build Configurations?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I've got a custom build configuration setup in my V.S. 2012 Win Phone 8 solution (distinct Configurations other than just Debug and Release) and am using SQLite (which cannot be built against the AnyCPU Platform) and cannot find a way to run the test kit since it insists on a "Release + AnyCPU" build.  Copying the contents of the actual output folder to "Bin\Release" doesn't seem to satisfy the test kit (nor did setting the output folder in the project file to "Bin\Release" for the appropriate configuration) and I can find no way to change the test kit settings/path.  Is this simply impossible or am I just missing something?

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686311/cant-use-store-test-kit-while-working-with-sqlite-in-windows-phone-8) but it's less than helpful and also incomplete (that post doesn't say anything about custom build configurations).  I have also sent negative feedback [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394032(v=vs.105).aspx) asking a similar question (but of course that's unlikely to be replied to).

I was going to add "store-test-kit" and "custom-build-config" tags to this but don't have the reputation to do so so I've added them in this note instead in case it helps with future searches.

My solution combines a number of projects spanning from Windows 8 Desktop to Windows 8 Phone (and including DLLs and other supporting dependecy projects including SQLite).  In order to build only what is needed I drastically customized my build configurations.  So e.g. I have:
N-Dbg, N-Rls, N-Str and P-DBG, P-Rls, P-Str as build Configurations.  These distingush from the Desktop ([N]ot phone) and [P]hone primary projects and the Dbg (debug) Rls (Release) and Str (Store) build sets.  I have a distinct Str build so that the live store code bits are excluded from the Release build which also leaves out all the extra Debug features.
As complicated as it all sounds it works really quite well in practice, until I need to build a "Release" version.  (And this is completely ignoring the platform part of the equation for which just selecting ARM might suffice, I really can't say because I have no good way to test it at the moment).

Ideally then what I want the Store Test Kit to test against is the P-Str build config.  I tried setting the configuration to output that set of files to "Bin\Release" which is where a brand new standard build config puts "Release\Any CPU" builds, but the Store Kit didn't like it.  It doesn't even list anything for a path to the XAP file that it's supposed to be testing.

After my initial post I did think to try making a new Release build config that was just setup the same as the P-Str build config but that also did not seem to make the Store Test Kit happy (though I admit that I am not 100% sure that I added the new build configuration completely accurately since it had been a long time since I created the custom config in the first place).

Does anyone out in the S.O. world have any experience with such a completely custom build configuration that might be able to help me out here?

Comment: Did you try building "Release + ARM"? I've found that works fine.

Comment: I've discovered that I was very close with the idea of copying the files to the Bin\Release location but there were a couple missing pieces. First I had to add a Release+AnyCPU entry to the project file (even though I never actually use it) apparently so that the Store Test Kit knows where to look for the xap. Second, I had to be sure to rename the xap file in the Bin\Release folder to ProjName_Release_AnyCPU.xap.  Once these things are done I can run the Test Kit. I'm not marking this as an answer because I think it's a more of a hack and I'd like a better option if possible.

Comment: Thank you so much. All I had to do was rename the xap file and move the location to the Bin\Release folder and voila the tests start working. On an arm build, didn't have to change the project file at all.

Comment: @TombMedia you should post this as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess after almost a full year if no one has found a better way I'll take the advice to call this the answer...

I was very close with the idea of copying the files to the Bin\Release location but there were a couple missing pieces. First I had to add a Release+AnyCPU entry to the project file (even though I never actually use it) apparently so that the Store Test Kit knows where to look for the xap. Second, I had to be sure to rename the xap file in the Bin\Release folder to ProjName_Release_AnyCPU.xap. Once these things are done I can run the Test Kit.